# How do I design my database and entity-relationship diagram more efficiently?

Tags: sql-server, database, diagram, entity-relationship

My question is more of a logical question. I want to design an EER diagram (might be some random database for like a school's student database or a company that sells cars etc.) The thing I would like to know is how to design it efficiently. For example, when to use inheritence or when to not. How to decide that. There could be so many more questions I guess. So I want to learn about this stuff. Could anyone recommend a good source for such applications?

Comment: Off-topic for SO - too broad and asks for recommendations that are off-site. Note - the diagram is just a tool used to design a database. Seems you need to educate yourself about relational theory and designing relational databases correctly. Once you understand the basics, you worry about "efficiency".

Comment: @SMor I think its a good question and if anyone gave it a good answer, it would be very useful for a lot of people. I didn't know this was off-topic. However, you could be more friendly.